# How can i see PostgreSQL UI in pgAdmin if the db is in Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin-4

I have installed one open-source project from docker and that project has a database in PostgreSQL. Now I want to see the database from pgAdmin 4 and when I am trying to connect with "host.docker.internal" I am getting an error see image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply do mapping port for your PostgreSQL (which is running inside Docker). and from your pgAdmin4 you'll connect using `localhost:<mapped_port>`

If you're using `docker-compose`

```yaml
services:
  postgre:
    ports:
      - "8080:5432"
```

If you're using `docker-cli`

```
docker run postgre -p 8080:5432
```

Then from pgAdmin4 connect to your database using `localhost:8080`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but the port is already mapped, still I am getting the same error

Comment: from pgAdmin4 can you try connect using `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a networking issue.

If port mapping does not work as suggested in other answers, try specifying the network as host for your container

If you are using docker run

```
--net=host
```

Or use the following on docker compose

```
network_mode: 'host'
```